# Software architectural style for adding new components/modules

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, components

I am looking for suggestions on which architectural style to choose which is well suited to handle the problem of adding new components/modules. I looked at component based architecture. But unsure about concrete implementation(design patterns to use) that how other parts of system(which are interested in performing tasks) will know when new modules available for same task. For example: A system can do Task A and Task B. For doing Task A there are 3 modules and for Task B 4. User wants to add a new module for Task A. Or user wants to remove some module for Task B.

Kindly guide me in right direction.

Comment: Sounds like a plugin system.

Comment: Make an interface for invoking task A. Let a module implement the interface. User can register the module. The module registers itself as a potential processor of task A. System A can invoke the module as a Task A Implementor. The way of registering this is similar to an observer pattern, although instead of sending update notifications, System A invokes the task handler.

Comment: Would you please provide some concrete design pattern examples?

Comment: @NicoSchertler, which design patterns I can use to implement this?

Comment: There are various possible patterns. The concrete choice depends on your scenario. *Strategy* is a good candidate.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, but how some other separate module will know what new algorithms are available for the task A? I want other modules to know which algorithms are available so that separate module will pick any algorithm according to some criteria.

Comment: Depends on your language and on the method how new modules are added (e.g. as new files in a folder). Then you just need a plugin registry as suggested by GolezTrol.